# find the max value from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dictionaries such as:

```
[{1: 0.4, 3: 0.5}, {1: 0.2, 3: 0.9}, {1: 0.3, 3: 0.1}]
```

I want to find the maximum of first key(1) and second key(3) from each list items
-> maximum of key(1) is 0.4
-> maximum of key(3) is 0.9
How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the desired value into an iterable and then look for the max.

```
data = [{1: 0.4, 3: 0.5}, {1: 0.2, 3: 0.9}, {1: 0.3, 3: 0.1}]

key = 1
max([d[key] for d in data])
```

Note that in the above example I create a list, with a list comprehension `[d[key] for d in data]`. Usually, when dealing with large input, creating a list is memory expensive and should be avoided. A similar result can be achieved with a generator yielding each element:

```
max(d[key] for d in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function can accept a `key` argument which specifies a one-argument function for ordering. The return is an element in list, in this case, the dictionary.

```py
dicts = [{1: 0.4, 3: 0.5}, {1: 0.2, 3: 0.9}, {1: 0.3, 3: 0.1}]

keys = [1, 3]

for key in keys:
    max_d = max(dicts, key=lambda d: d[key])
    print(f'maximum of key({key}) is {max_d[key]}')
```

```
maximum of key(1) is 0.4
maximum of key(3) is 0.9
```